# convert only special chars using htmlspecialchars inside iconv

Tags: php

I have to convert the JSON response from an external application from UTF-8 to windows-1251 because of the specifics of that application, so it's a must.

`iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $element->text)`

Due to those specifics, I also must convert the special symbols (?,!, etc.) in the response from "normal" to html entities. But obviously if I use `iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", htmlspecialchars($element->text)`, then all the text from the response gets converted, and I can't validate the response. So how do I apply `htmlspecialchars` only on the special symbols and not on all of the response? I know it must have to do with regex, but I don't quite imagine what I must do here.

Comment: Might perhaps make more sense to use str_replace to begin with … array of characters to replace, array of entities they need to be replaced with …

Comment: I came up with `preg_replace("[\W]", htmlspecialchars("[\W]"), $element->text)` but all text of the response except cpecial chars gets replaced with �

Comment: That is wrong for multiple reasons. First of all, this calls `htmlspecialchars` first, and then only passes the return value as second parameter to `preg_replace`, and secondly, you are feeding the static text `[\W]` to it, this has no connection to what your regular expression matched in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't imagine how to correctly use your advice.

Comment: What, on how to use str_replace? The manual has examples for that. // Maybe start with a proper description of what exactly you need to replace, and why. You say “the special symbols (?,!, etc.)”, but neither does htmlspecialchars do anything to ? or ! in the first place, nor are these “special characters” in regard to HTML. And what this is supposed to have to do with the character encoding, is even more unclear.

Comment: I must convert `!` to `&amp;#33;` etc. Because that's what the external app's client side sends in, but on its server side it's regular `!`. And that applies to all punctuation. Maybe I incorrectly called it special chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a quick example that uses preg_replace_callback to replace the individual matched characters with `&#NN;`, using `ord` to get the `NN` part from the character:

```
$text = 'abc!def?ghi';

$text = preg_replace_callback('#[!?]#', function($matches) {
  return '&#'.ord($matches[0]).';';
}, $text);

echo htmlspecialchars($text); // will result in abc&#33;def&#63;ghiabc!def?ghi
```

(`htmlspecialchars` is only used here so that you can *see* those entities when viewing the result in the browser, of course you don’t actually apply it to the variable in the context of what your script needs to do.)

The list of characters inside the [] can be appended, you just need to take care of proper escaping with a backslash should any of the characters have a special meaning in regex to begin with.

Comment: I don't know how, but it magically worked. Even though in Charles I see only `�` signs instead of letters in the response, but they correctly display in my database. Now I can successfully validate the hash of the client's request with that of the record from the external app's server side, even if it contains punctuatuon. I'm much less than a beginner in PHP, so I'd appreciate more explanation, some links maybe. Huge thanks anyway!

Comment: I don’t know what Charles is, but if that is not the actual target application, then this might simply be due to the fact that you encoded this in windows-1251, and Charles still assumes it was actually UTF-8 … or something like that. What exactly could you use more explanation on, how the code I have shown works, or something else?

Comment: preg_replace_callback basically allows you to pass the matched parts of your expression to a callback function, so that you don’t have to specify the replacement “static”, but let the function determine it dynamically. And the `ord` function gets the position of the character in a single-byte encoding (which is why it works here, with the data encoded in windows-1251, with UTF-8 that would not have worked to begin with.)

Comment: Charles is a web debugging proxy software, I use it to see the output of requests and responses without having to output to the browser or text file. `echo iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", preg_replace_callback('#[!?]#', function($matches) {
  return '&#'.ord($matches[0]).';';` basically displays all of the text EXCEPT punctuation as `�` signs. But I forgot, I pass the UTF-8 text from the external app's server side to the database, so that's why it displays fine there. But the encoded text is only needed for checksum comparison, so it's fine.

Comment: I understood it partially, but not the part about the position of the character. I might need to google about it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Every character has a position in the code table of the character encoding used, like you might know in ASCII the space character is on position 32, the big A is at 65, and so on. The functions `ord` and its counterpart `chr` allow you to “translate” from on to the other, character to position, or position to character. (For character encodings that use only one byte, with a multi-byte encoding such as UTF-8 this would only work for characters at code points <= 255.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand now.